# How do I save 2 radgrids in batch edit mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have 2 RadGrid (rgRole and rgRecei) on a page in batch edit. i'm using OnBatchEditCommand function in code behind to save new record to Database by stored procedure.
I tried to use 1 html button to call to js func

```
    function SaveRg(){ $find('rgRole').get_batchEditingManager().saveChanges('rgRole_ctl00');
        return false;            
        $find('rgRecei').get_batchEditingManager().saveChanges('rgRecei_ctl00');
        return false;
    }
```

But it only call the rgRecei_BatchEditCommand (the second grid). So how can i call 2 BatchEditCommand func by 1 button and RadButton is better than html button.

Answer (score 0):

```
function SaveRg(){ $find('rgRole').get_batchEditingManager().saveChanges('rgRole_ctl00');                 
        $find('rgRecei').get_batchEditingManager().saveChanges('rgRecei_ctl00');
        return false;
```

I believe you should only return once from each function or block. Changed your code.

Comment: i changed it and put 2 debug point to rgRole_BatchEditCommand and rgRecei_BatchEditCommand, but it still overlook the first.